# blastn not found + google colaboratory

Tags: google-colaboratory

How to solve this:

ApplicationError: Non-zero return code 127 from 'blastn -out /content/output/kitasatospora/out.txt -outfmt 6 -query /content/sequence_USA_utah.fasta -subject /content/sequence_USA_utah.fasta', message '/bin/sh: 1: blastn: not found'

Answer (score 1):

You need to install it first.

```
!apt install ncbi-blast+
```

Then, you can run `blastn`.